# LIBGDX Texture filtering on different Sprite methods

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to use the Nearest filter when scaling up my sprite (because it's pixel-style) but I need the Linear filter for rotating the sprite so it doesn't look ugly. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you ever have to rotate it while it is scaled up?

Comment: No the sprite is scaled up when created and then rotated and never rescaled ever again.

Comment: You could maybe scale it up in the source image with no filter in Gimp or Photoshop. Then use a mip map linear filter in the game. Not sure how good that would look. Alternatively, you could continue using nearest filtering, but draw everything to a screen-sized FrameBuffer, and then draw the frame buffer texture to the screen using an FXAA shader (although this might be too slow on mobile).

Comment: Scaling up the source image is what I didn't want in the first place because  it saves memory when the image is smaller and the other stuff is too complicated for me (I just started learning LIBGDX). But thanks anyway!